# package conflict android for different apps

Tags: android, package, conflict

I have two different apps. 
one for mobiles and 2nd for tablets.

Both have the basic package name same and one more thing mobile app can also run on tablets too.

for Mobile package is

> com.app.devx

for Tablet package is

> com.app.devx.tablet

when I am trying to install tablet app on tablet while mobile app is already install I am getting this error.

> **the package conflicts with an existing package by the same name**

any idea why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Package names should be unique. You cannot have two apps with the same package name on your phone/tablet.

Comment: I Think
**com.app.devx** & **com.app.devx.tablet** are two different packages as it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

1. In app/Build.gradle:

   ```
   signingConfigs {
       mobile{
           storeFile file("keystore")
           storePassword "secret"
           keyAlias "aliasForFlavor1"
           keyPassword "secretFlavor1"
       }

       tablet{
           storeFile file("keystore")
           storePassword "secret"
           keyAlias "aliasForFlavor2"
           keyPassword "secretFlavor2"
       }
   }

   productFlavors {
       def signingConfigsMobile = signingConfigs.mobile
       def signingConfigsTablet = signingConfigs.tablet


       mobile{
         buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_TABLET", "false"
           signingConfig signingConfigsMobile
       }
       tablet{
       applicationIdSuffix ".tablet"

           buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_TABLET", "true"
           signingConfig signingConfigsTablet
       }
   }
   ```

   2. After doing above follow these steps :

      > Select Build > select Build varaint > then select 
      >   mobileDebug/tabletDebug 
      >   Run` your app